# Doxygen Alias with multiple commands

Tags: alias, doxygen

I do have some problems to define an Alias definition in doxygen when I have to use multiple commands in the alias definition.
What I am trying to achieve is actually the output of sample `DD_32` below.

I currently don't know why the output of `@DD{22, Test Description}` looks different. Also tried to provide escaped quotes to the ALIAS definition, but still. No luck.

My alias definition is as follows:

```
ALIASES               += DD{2}="\page DD_\1 \"Design \1\" \brief \2 @par Implementation:"
```

For testing I use the following code:

```
/**
 * @page DD_31 Design 31
 * @brief Descrition
 * @par Implementation:
 */

/**
 * @DD{22, Test Description}
 */
```

I would suspect, that the output is identical, but it looks like in the screenshot provided below:

[image: Current result]

As you can see, the \brief description is actually part of the page name.
Any hints how I could fix this issue?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are already using @ par why not use @ with brief and page as well otherwise try to escape the backslash of \page and \brief  to \\page and \\brief.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just tried both of your suggested solutions, teh variant with the @ symbols `ALIASES               += DD{2}="@page DD_\1 Design \1 @brief \2 @par Implementation:" ` produces identical output to the screenshot posted above. The variant with the escaped backslashes produces no output at all.

Comment: I now did some tests an the problem here is the fact that \page reads till the end of the line as part of the title (see documentation of the \page command). No solution yet.

Comment: I didn't find a possibility within the current doxygen version. I pushed a proposed patch to github (pull request 602, https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/602).

Comment: Thanks, really looking forward that this pull request get's accepted.

Comment: Seems like this was once fixed and then broken again. In 1.8.14 you could do this by inserting ^^ into the alias, but in 1.8.15 this was broken, it seems like a fix has been comitted since here https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6828 but this is not yet released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness;

As proposed in the comments by [albert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1657886/albert), his [pull request](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/602) implements physical newlines in an alias by placing ^^ in between separate commands.

So, for example:

ALIASES += DD{2}="@page DD_\1 "Design \1" \brief \2 ^^ @par Implementation:"